# WP7: Save a contact with predefined details

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am doing a Windows Phone 7 project, and is retrieving personal details for a person based on his phone number via a webservice.

I'd like to allow the user to save this data as a contact; Ideally I would like to show the Edit Contact dialog with all the fields pre-filled based on the data I retrieve.

I know I can do this:

```
        var saveTask = new SavePhoneNumberTask();
        saveTask.PhoneNumber = phone;            
        saveTask.Show();
```

But I need to pre-set all the other properties for the task also. Is there any way to do this in Windows Phone 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WP7 SDK allows an application to save either a phone number or an email address to a new or existing contact (with [SavePhoneNumberTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.saveemailaddresstask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and [SaveEmailAddressTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.saveemailaddresstask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)). There is currently no way to set other contact information.